# how do i convert checkboxes to string for posting using Jquery and ASP.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to convert a checkbox into a string that can be emailed using my asp.net code.  The code below uses a Jquery script to convert the html form into ASP.net which works fine.  However, the form is not converting the checkboxes.  It always brings them in as No, even when checked.  Other than that the form works perfectly.  It sends the email fine, all of the other fields work fine.

Here is the HTML code relating to the checkboxes.

```
    <input name="check1" id="check1" type="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="txt_check1" id="txt_check1" />
    <input name="check2" id="check2" type="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="txt_check2" id="txt_check2" />
    <input name="check3" id="check3" type="checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="txt_check3" id="txt_check3" />
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the JQUERY and/or ASP.net code.

```
Case 4 Contact Form
Response.Write(sendMailSE(Convert.ToString(Request.Form("name")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field1")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field2")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field3")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("field4")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("checkbox1")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("checkbox2")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("checkbox3")), Convert.ToString(Request.Form("comments"))))

    Public Function sendMailSE(ByVal field1, ByVal field2, ByVal field3, ByVal field4, ByVal checkbox1, ByVal checkbox2, ByVal checkbox3, ByVal comments) As String
    Try
        Const ToAddress As String = "jdoe@abcd.com"

        '(1) Create the MailMessage instance
        Dim mm As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("jdoe@abcd.com", ToAddress)

        'create cocantenated string for body of message
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()


        '(2) Assign the MailMessage's properties
        mm.Subject = "Contact Us: "
        sb.Append("Contact Us: " + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("----------------------------------" + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Date " + DateTime.Now() + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field1: " + field1 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field2:" + field2 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field3: " + field3 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Field4: " + field4 + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Checkbox1 " + IIf(checkbox1, "Yes", "No") + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Checkbox2 " + IIf(checkbox2, "Yes", "No") + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Checkbox3 " + IIf(checkbox3, "Yes", "No") + vbCrLf)
        sb.Append("Comments: " + comments + vbCrLf)
```

I have removed the code below this line as it is immaterial.

Here is my JQUERY code pertaining to the posting of the function:

```
function check() {
              $('#check1').change(function check(){
              if($(this).is(":checked"))
                 {
                     $('#txt_check1').val("true");
                 }
              else
                 {
                     $('#txt_check1').val("false");
                 }
             });
            $('#check2').change(function check(){
              if($(this).is(":checked"))
                 {
                     $('#txt_check2').val("true");
                 }
              else
                 {
                     $('#txt_check2').val("false");
                 }
            });
            $('#check3').change(function check(){
              if($(this).is(":checked"))
                 {
                     $('txt_check3').val("true");
                 }
              else
                 {
                     $('txt_check3').val("false");
                 }
            });
}

function sendmailse() {
                $.post('RequestForms/sendmail.aspx', {
                    ch: 4, 
                    name: $("#sename").val(),
                    filer: $("#filer").val(),
                    filingagent: $("#filingagent").val(),
                    phone: $("#sephone").val(),
                    email: $("#seemail").val(),
                    checkbox1: $("#txt_check1").val(),
                    checkbox2: $("#txt_check2").val(),
                    checkbox3: $("#txt_check3").val(), 
                    comments: $("#secomments").val() 
                },
                function (data) {                       
                    $("#sename").val("");
                    $("#filer").val("");
                    $("#filingagent").val("");
                    $("#sephone").val("");
                    $("#seemail").val("");
                    $("#txt_check1").val("");
                    $("#txt_check2").val("");
                    $("#txt_check3").val("");
                    $("#secomments").val("") 
                });
              }
```

It is not working still.  As I said before, the all of the other fields are working correctly except the checkboxes.  The form emails fine but the checkboxes come in as No every time.  If you look at my asp and jquery code there must be a problem somewhere in there.

Comment: it looks like your CheckBox param being sent in has an uppercase C and the Checkbox in the IIF statement has a lowercase. Is this down to case sensitivity?

Comment: Good catch.  I changed the field names just for reason of posting, but it matches in my real form. still having the issue

Comment: any additional solutions?  I am hungry to give out a solve.

Answer (score 0):

When the check box isn't ticked it might not be submit a value. I resolved this in a previous project by adding hidden input fields which get overwritten when the check box is true.

```
 <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Checkbox1" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Checkbox1" />
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.  There is something specific with the checkbox data in the asp code I provided.  I'm wondering if you can't use a convertostring function on a checkbox in this way.

Comment: You should be able to use a convert to string method. have you tried stepping through it to see what the value received is? Or sending this in a get instead of a post and try read the query string? Some times a checkbox can return "true, false" for true and "false" for false. If you aren't getting any response at all try seeing if you get a value for submitting it when the checkbox is ticket and again for unticked. Failing all that please provide your html, jquery code

Comment: Instead of using .val() on the checkbox id element try using .checked, it should return a Boolean.

Comment: any additional solutions?  I am hungry to give out a solve.

Comment: check out my new string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187739/checkboxes-not-working-using-html-jquery-and-asp-net-to-send-contact-form, as this question is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Update values:
Control with Jquery in code of javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready
        (
            function()
            {
                 $('#check1').change(function(){
                      if($(this).is(":checked"))
                         {
                             $('#txt_check1').val("true");
                         }
                      else
                         {
                             $('#txt_check1').val("false");
                         }
                 });


                 $('#check2').change(function(){
                      if($(this).is(":checked"))
                         {
                             $('#txt_check2').val("true");
                         }
                      else
                         {
                             $('#txt_check2').val("false");
                         }
                 });


                 $('#check3').change(function(){
                      if($(this).is(":checked"))
                         {
                             $('#txt_check3').val("true");
                         }
                      else
                         {
                             $('#txt_check3').val("false");
                         }
                 });
            }
        );
</script>
```

The inputs id and name of check and text must be differents, in your case it would look like this:

```
   <input name="check1" id="check1" type="checkbox"><label for="check1"></label>
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="txt_check1" id="txt_check1" />

   <input name="check2" id="check2" type="checkbox"><label for="check2"></label>                                          
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="txt_check2" id="txt_check2" />

   <input name="check3" id="check3" type="checkbox"><label for="check3"></label>
   <input type="hidden" value="false" name="txt_check3" id="txt_check3" />
```

And your function should get the value of txt:

```
   function sendmailse() {
        $.post('formsend.aspx', { ch: 4, field1: $("#f1").val(), field2: $("#f2").val(), field3: $("#f3").val(), field4: $("#f4").val(), checkbox1: $("#txt_check1").val(), checkbox2: $("#txt_check2").val(), checkbox3: $("#txt_check3").val(), comments: $("#comments").val() }, function (data) {                       
            $("#f1").val("");
            $("#f2").val("");
            $("#f3").val("");
            $("#f4").val("");
            $("#txt_check1").val("");
            $("#txt_check2").val("");
            $("#txt_check3").val("");
            $("#comments").val("") 
         });
    }
```

Comment: I think you may be close with the JQUERY function.  I added my JQUERY and HTML code.  Please let me know how I should change it.

Comment: I updated the code with the values you passed can check?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When it comes in, it still says "No" even when it is checked every time.  If I leave it unchecked it still says no.  Please advise.

Comment: any additional solutions?  I am hungry to give out a solve.

Comment: check out my new string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187739/checkboxes-not-working-using-html-jquery-and-asp-net-to-send-contact-form, as this question is not resolved.